# Git mirror with worktree pre-2.5

Tags: git

I'm curating an index of curated OSS lists and I'm also writing scripts to back them up automatically that is, the lists and all resources they refer to.

The backups serve a dual purpose:

1. Full mirrors in case the repos go down or are vandalized
2. Local copies to browse (I'm writing a standalone Markdown server for this)

Now, so far I've used `git clone --mirror` with `git remote update` but to my suprise this also meant I don't get a worktree, which I need to be able to browse the repositories. I'm stuck on `git 2.1.4` so I can't use `git worktree add`.

(Yes, I should have read the docs for `--bare`, but instead I found out when my Markdown server was near finished failed to show me any files.)

Now here's my question: is there any way of cloning/updating a Git repository that:

- appends only (so no blobs or branches are ever removed),
- tracks all remote branches,
- has a working tree with a configurable branch/commit and also
- works with `git 2.1.4`?

Edit: [link for anyone who's interested in the project](https://gitlab.com/willemmali/awesome-awesome), it uses `yaml` for data instead of the usual Markdown to make it machine-readable (the `README.md` is generated based on the `yaml` files).